# Thymeleaf templates - Is there a way to decorate a template instead of including a template fragment?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am working with Thymeleaf for the first time, and I need a clarification about the templates. If I correctly understand the documentation, I can *include* a template - or just a fragment of it - in my page. So for example, I can write something like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head th:include="template/layout :: header">
    </head>
    <body>
        Hello world
        <div th:include="template/layout :: footer"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

But what I want is in fact the opposite way of using the template : instead of including template fragment in the page, I want to include the page **inside** my template, something like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>

    <div id="my-template-header">...</div>

    <div id="the-content">
        <!-- include here the content of the current page visited by the user -->
        ???
    </div>

    <div id="my-template-footer">...</div>
</body>
```

In others words, is there a way to have an equivalent of the [Sitemesh decorators tags](http://wiki.sitemesh.org/display/sitemesh/Tag+References) in Thymeleaf?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect ?

Comment: @DennisJaamann I'm currently testing it, indeed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ok, as stated by Sotirios Delimanolis, Thymeleaf does not support that way of using template, or should I say "*Hierarchical layouts*", as explained by Daniel Fernandez in [this thread](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/116237-petclinic-html5-with-thymeleaf?p=586814#post586814).

As sitemesh and Thymeleaf are compatible, it seems that I have to use both solutions. Too bad.

Edit: As suggested by DennisJaamann in a comment, I finally used [Thymeleaf Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect), a view dialect that provides the feature I was looking for.

The working code:

First I add the `LayoutDialect` class:

```
@Bean
public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    ServletContextTemplateResolver resolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    //NB, selecting HTML5 as the template mode.
    resolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    resolver.setCacheable(false);
    return resolver;
}
```

Then, I create the template (for ex. `templates/layout.html`), and add the `layout:fragment` information where I want to put the content of the current page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
    <div id="my-template-header">...</div>

    <div id="the-content" layout:fragment="content">
        <!-- include here the content of the current page visited by the user -->
    </div>

    <div id="my-template-footer">...</div>
</body>
```

and the page will refers to the template with the attribute `layout:decorator`:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      layout:decorator="templates/layout">
<body>

    <div layout:fragment="content">
        Hello world
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Pro forma you should then add the code that solved it and accept your own answer :)

Comment: @DennisJaamann you're right, I wanted to add the code, even if it is exactly the same as the one provided in the documentation of Layout project. And to accept my answer, I have to wait tomorrow :)

Comment: hello, do you know if there is a way to use the layout dialect where I could keep the parent's content, instead of overwriting it? meaning: the final result would render `<!-- include here the content of the current page visited by the user --> Hello world` instead of just `Hello world`. This is, of course, without having to move `<!-- include here the content of the current page visited by the user -->` outside `<div layout:fragment="content">`. thanx

Answer (score 69):

with Thymeleaf 2.1, you can write something like that:

Create the template (for ex. templates/layout.html), and add the **th:fragment="page"** information in html tag and define the content area with **th:include="this :: content"** information:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:fragment="page">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        layout page
        <div th:include="this :: content"/>
        layout footer
    </body>
</html>
```

Now create the page that will include this template adding **th:include="templates/layout :: page"** in html tag and put your main content inside a div with **th:fragment="content"**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:include="templates/layout :: page">
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div th:fragment="content">
            my page content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In layout page you can use ***this*** (th:include="this :: content") or suppress this option (th:include=":: content"). It seems like jsf facelets I think.

Comment: Thank you, this fits in nicely for us who used to jsp tag

Comment: @VadimFerderer: I don't get your comment. This is working nicely - you can make your layout page in <th:block th:fragment="page"> and head tags are included in every page, where you will use that layout page.

Comment: @VadimFerderer Your comment is not constructive...what is the problem with the head resources?

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and add this to your SpringTemplateEngine:

```
@Bean
@Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect());

    return templateEngine;
}
```

If now create a folder named template in your views folder.

views/home.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
  layout:decorator="template/layout">
 <body>
  <div layout:fragment="content">
    Hello world
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

views/layout/layout.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-spring4-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
        xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
    <head>
      </head>
        <body>
          <div id="content" layout:fragment="content">
          </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't. A possible solution would be to create a `ViewResolver` that always forwards to your `decorator` file, but at the same time put `Model` attributes that would have the actual path to the fragment you want to include.