# How to check Thymeleaf fragment is defined

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

How do I check a Thymeleaf fragment is defined when using ["template decoration instead of inclusion" technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896915/thymeleaf-templates-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-a-template-instead-of-including)?

In below example of **template.html** I only want the script tag to be rendered when the fragment is defined

```
<html th:fragment="page" xmlns:th="...">
  ...
  <div class="container" th:include="this :: content"></div>
  <script th:include="this :: script"></script>
  ...
</html>
```

But here in my **index.html** which uses the template above, no script fragment is defined but the script tag will still render anyway

```
<html th:include="template :: page">
  ...
  <div th:fragment="content">
    ...
  </div>
</html>
```

I've tried `th:if="#{this :: script}"` but no luck

Comment: Did you try `th:replace` instead of `th:include` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I played a little (...) with Thymeleaf, and here are my conclusions.

In the following, I will use `tag` for any given tag (`div`, `script`, `span`, etc.) and `fragment` an acceptable fragment syntax (`this :: script`, `this :: content`, `template :: #menu`, etc.)

When you use `<tag th:include="fragment"/>`,Thymeleaf allways generates a `<tag>...</tag>`. If it does not exist, the content is empty giving `<tag></tag>`. If the fragment exists, the content becomes the content of the fragment. For exemple using `<div th:"other :: #foo/>` for a fragment `<p id="foo">bar</p>` gives `<div>bar</div>`

When you use `<tag th:replace="fragment"/>`, Thymeleaf tries to replace it with the full fragment, tag included. with the following special cases :

- if the fragment does not exist, Thymeleaf does not insert anything
- if the fragment is identified by a `th:fragment="id"`, Thymeleaf removes the `th:fragment` (ex: `<p th:fragment="foo">bar</p>` gives `<p>bar</p>`, whatever `tag` is).
- if the fragment is identified by a dom element, Thymeleaf keeps the dom element (ex : `<p id="foo">bar</p>` gives `<p id="foo">bar</p>`, whatever `tag` is)

So, if you want to include the `<script>` fragment only if it exists, you simply have to identify it by `<script th:fragment ...>...</script>` when it exists and include it in your layout by :

```
<script th:replace="this :: script"/>
```