# Trying to ignore unused layout fragment in Thymeleaf Layout Dialect

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Does anyone know if it's possible to hide a layout:fragment if it is not specified in the calling page?

For example, I have a page layout.html that has something like (where there is a separate fragment.html file with header and footer fragments):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      th:lang = "en">
<head>
  <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE">TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header layout:replace="fragment :: header">HEADER</header>
  <section layout:fragment="messages">MESSAGES</section>
  <section layout:fragment="content">CONTENT</section>
  <footer layout:replace="fragment :: footer">FOOTER</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

If in a calling page to the layout that I don't want to include the "messages" fragment, is there a way to do it by just not including that code?  For example (say, simple.html):

```
<html layout:decorator="layout">
<head>
  <title th:text=#{PAGETITLE_SIMPLE}>SIMPLE PAGE TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section layout:fragment="content">
    <p>Put in some random content for the body of the simple page</p>
  </section>
</body>
```

This will still put into the rendered HTML the text "MESSAGES" inside a <section>-tag.

I have been able to put into this simple.html

```
<section layout:fragment="messages" th:remove="all"></section>
```

But this seems somewhat sloppy and was wondering if there was a way to hide that from the users of the layout by putting the logic in the layout to ignore that fragment altogether.

Using Spring 4.1.6, Thymleaf 2.1.4, and Layout Dialect 1.3.3.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by applying the methods posted by Serge Ballesta in [How to check Thymeleaf fragment is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574941/how-to-check-thymeleaf-fragment-is-defined) to the layout dialect.

This is what the rewritten layout.html looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout"
      th:lang = "en">
<head>
  <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE">TITLE</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header layout:replace="fragment :: header">HEADER</header>
  <section layout:replace="this :: messages">MESSAGES</section>
  <section layout:fragment="content">CONTENT</section>
  <footer layout:replace="fragment :: footer">FOOTER</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

This way, if the calling page (simple.html) only has the <section> for `content`, no HTML will be rendered for the section for messages.  But if the page did have the following, it will be included as intended:

```
<section layout:fragment="messages">
  <p>Message 1</p>
  <p>Message 2</p>
</section>
```