# What type of operation and syntax for them are possible on Thymeleaf 3 fragment expression?

Tags: thymeleaf

With Thymeleaf 3 it is possible to pass fragment from page to template via `~{:: selector}` syntax.

What kind of operation are possible on that object?

Fragment can be used inside expression:

```
<div th:fragment="name(arg)">
  <div th:replace="${arg} :? _"></div>
</div>
```

Can I extract only part of fragment inside fragment with something like (following is incorrect syntax!!):

```
<div th:fragment="name(arg)">
  <div th:replace="${arg :: script} :? _"></div>
  <div th:replace="${arg}.filter('script'} :? _"></div>
  <div th:replace="${xpath(${arg},'script')} :? _"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE** I introspected to what fragment expression is resolved with:

```
<th:block th:text="${bodyContent.class}" />
```

which is [org.thymeleaf.standard.expression.Fragment](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/standard/expression/Fragment.html). It has:

```
<th:block th:text="${bodyContent.templateModel.class}" />
```

[TemplateModel](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/engine/TemplateModel.html) which can be rendered via `toString()` or `write(Writer writer)`. I don't see easy way to filter `Fragment` content...

Answer (score 0):

I saw [Thymeleaf templates - Is there a way to decorate a template instead of including a template fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896915/thymeleaf-templates-is-there-a-way-to-decorate-a-template-instead-of-including) technique which I tried to employ.

Thymeleaf v2.1 and 3 allows referencing templates/fragment mix to itself.

Lets look to template:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <body>
       <nav></nav>
       <div th:replace="this :: body"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

and to page:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      th:replace="thymeleaf/layout/default :: html">
    <body>
       XXX
    </body>
</html>
```

Above code produces infinite sequence of `<body><nav></nav>` as CSS selector referenced from template to `body`'s template.

To move reference to page I added more complicated CSS style selector:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" class="htmlFrag">
    <body>
       <nav></nav>
       <div th:replace="this :: html[!class]/body"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am not sure how it is possible to have template and page in same scope for selector matching but it works...

Advanced templating with CSS/JS handling can be represented as:

```
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" class="htmlFrag">
    <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

       <title th:text="~{::html[!class]/head/title/text()}"></title>

       <link rel='stylesheet' href='/webjars/...">
       <div th:replace="this :: html[!class]/head/link"/>

       <script src="/webjars/..."></script>
       <div th:replace="this :: html[!class]/head/script"/>
    </head>
    <body>
       <nav></nav>
       <div th:replace="this :: html[!class]/body"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE** I've got responce from developers https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/626

Thymeleaf uses pull-based or fragment-inclusion-based layout architecture or by default.

With [Layout Dialect](https://github.com/ultraq/thymeleaf-layout-dialect) it is possible to use hierarchical layout style and it is preferred to do this.